# Convert huge if else statement into a loop in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to format a number to be displayed in a more friendly way. At the moment, the code is really difficult to update and it's huge and clumsy.

```
function abb(){
    if(m>=1 && m<999){
        gold_display = m;
    }else if(m>999 && m<999999){
        var b = (m / 1000).toFixed(3);
        gold_display = b+"k";
    }else if (m>999999 && m<999999999){
        var b = (m / 1000000).toFixed(3);
        gold_display = b+"m";
    }else if (m>999999999 && m<999999999999){
        var b = (m / 1000000000).toFixed(3);
        gold_display = b+"b";
    }else if (m>999999999999 && m<99999999999999){
        var b = (m / 1000000000000).toFixed(3);
        gold_display = b+"t";
    }
}
```

EDIT: THIS WOULD BE THE CODE:

```
function abb(){
        if(m>=1 && m<1000){
            gold_display = m;
        }else if(m>999 && m<1000000){
            var b = (m / 1000).toFixed(3);
            gold_display = b+"k";
        }else if (m>999999 && m<1000000000){
            var b = (m / 1000000).toFixed(3);
            gold_display = b+"m";
        }else if (m>999999999 && m<1000000000000){
            var b = (m / 1000000000).toFixed(3);
            gold_display = b+"b";
        }else if (m>999999999999 && m<100000000000000){
            var b = (m / 1000000000000).toFixed(3);
            gold_display = b+"t";
        }
    }
```

Yeah it's akward but it was the only solution that came up into my mind, is there a way to convert this into a loop and shrink the code?

I'm thinking in saving the letters "k", "m", "b","t" in an array because I want to go higher to "q", "qi","s", etc.

Thanks and sorry if the question is kinda stupid :(

Comment: array with min/max/divisor and then loop over it?

Comment: Please note `if (x < 10) ... else if (x > 10)` doesn't catch case `x === 10`

Comment: Thanks @PaulS. updated the code above!

Comment: Just curious, wont you pretty quickly need a system for handling numbers larger than javascript max number?

Answer (score 2):

Count how many times you need to divide by `1000` before you are under `1000`

```
function bigNumber(big) {
    let divisor = 1,
        steps = 0,
        small = big;
    while (small >= 1000) {
        divisor *= 1000;
        small = big / divisor;
        ++steps;
    }
    return {steps, divisor, small};
}
let gold = 123456789,
    foo = bigNumber(gold);

foo.small.toFixed(3) + ['', 'k', 'm', 'b', 't'][foo.steps];
// "123.457m"
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not much but one simplification of your code is to eliminate the lower-bound checking since the if/else-if structure will take care of that:

```
function abb(m) {
  if (m < 1) {
    // some kind of error?
  } else if (m < 1000) {
    return m;
  } else if (m < 1000000) {
    return (m/1000).toFixed(3) + "k";
  } else if (m < 1000000000) {
    return (m/1000000).toFixed(3) + "m";
  } else {
    // and so on
  }
}
```

You could do something more clever but I think it is probably best to be simple about it.

But if I understand your code correctly, you're trying to format numbers as thousands ("k"), millions ("m"), billions ("b") etc.  Why not look at a library for this such as http://numeraljs.com/?

Specifically, you can use this code:

```
var numeral = require('numeral').language('en');
```

to import the numeral.js library, and then this code to perform the formatting:

```
var str = numeral(12345678).format("0.0a");// "12.3m"
var str = numeral(1234).format("0.0a");// "1.2k"
```

etc.

Answer (score 1):

Full disclosure: this solution comes with the benefit of no for loop, but it does have some added complexity.

Take the logarithm of `m`. If  `1 <= m< 999` then `0 <= exponent < 3`. Similarly, if `1000 <= m < 999999` then `3 <= exponent < 6`, and so on. You can see the pattern here, every prefix covers a range of 3 in the logarithmic scale. So you could do something like the following:

```
function abb(m){
    var prefixes = ["","k","m","b","t"];
    var log = Math.log10(m);
    var prefixRange = parseInt(log/3, 10);
    var prefix = prefixes[prefixRange];

    return (m / Math.pow(1000, prefixRange)).toFixed(3) + prefix;
}
```

Actually, in the case of very large numbers, the above will break, so `prefixRange = parseInt(log/3, 10)` needs to be changed to `prefixRange = Math.min(parseInt(log/3, 10), 4)`,to ensure we don't read beyond the length of array `prefixes`.

Also, notice that toFixed is not really to be trusted for large numbers in this case. `999999999 / 1000000` gives `1000.000`, which I guess is not what you want. Better to round with floor in this case. Since you are only interested in the first  digits (3 for the integer and 3 for the decimal part), you can first get those 6 digits and then divide by 1000.

A better function, addressing both issues is:

```
function abb(m){
    var prefixes = ["","k","m","b","t"];
    var log = Math.log10(m);
    var prefixRange = Math.min(parseInt(log/3, 10), 4);
    var prefix = prefixes[prefixRange];

    return Math.floor((m / Math.pow(1000, prefixRange - 1)))/1000 + prefix;
}
```

Comment: Excellent answer Pedro! Pointing out the problem with rounding is especially important.